# Can you insert an if statement in php email

Tags: php, email, if-statement

```
// from the form
$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

// set here
$subject = "Contact form submitted!";
$to = 'your@email.com';

$body = HTML
$message
HTML;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

// send the email
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

// redirect afterwords, if needed
header('Location: thanks.html');
```

The question is, weather or not you can insert a php if statement inside the html email body or the best way to add it in there.  I'm creating a detailed inventory and once submitted, it needs to be email to an email.  But I don't want to email the full Inventory (including empty inputs), It should only email the fields that have something other than 0. I was thinking:

```
if ($armChair > 0) { echo 'Arm Chairs: ' . $_POST['armChair']; } ]
```

But it doesn't seem to actually work... any ideas?

Comment: Apparently you're new to php or even programming. You need to understand more of the bases, the message can be whatever you want, and you can use logic to construct it, but you don't echo it, you concatenate until you get the final message that will be sent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a badly constructed question.

Yes, you can definitely do that but you need to do it in a way that is sane. We can't tell by what you posted here since you just plugged in "HTML" where the body is defined.

```
$body = "Hi there,\r\n";
$body .= $armChair > 0 ? "Arm Chairs: ".$_POST['armCharis']."\r\n" : "";
$body.= "some more text";
```

If you mean overwrite a segment of $message, yes you can do that as well using something like machine tags {INVENTORY} or the likes...

```
$message = $armChair > 0 ? str_replace('{INVENTORY}', "Arm Chairs: ".$_POST['armCharis']."\r\n", $message) : "";
```

which of course requires the string {INVENTORY} somewhere in your $message var

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.  I have a large inventory form for house hold items.  I want to be able to email the form to an email address once submitted... but I don't want it to print every single input... I want it to print when there is a value greater than 0.  Make more sense?